# trouble understanding movement along local and global space in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
CharacterController _charController;

// ...

moveInputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
moveInputZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveInputX, 0, moveInputZ);
movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);

movement.y = -9.81f;

movement *= Time.deltaTime;
movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
_charController.Move(movement);
```

I have a player that rotates and I want to make him move to his local direction but i don't understand when I remove `movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);` from the code it moves to global direction which doesn't make any sense because this line of code converts the direction from local to global space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `CharacterController.Move` expects a vector in world space. Sadly, the documentation on that has never been clear about that.

When you calculate `movement` here:

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveInputX, 0, moveInputZ);
```

You can see that it doesn't take the rotation of the character's transform into account. In order for it to do that, you want to find what this vector looks like in world space when interpreted as being in the character's local space. That's exactly what this line does:

```
movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
```

It converts `movement` from local space to world space.

The [2018.1 `CharacterController.Move` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) actually uses `transform.TransformDirection` in its example:

> ```
> using UnityEngine;
> using System.Collections;
>
> // The GameObject is made to bounce using the space key.
> // Also the GameOject can be moved forward/backward and left/right.
> // Add a Quad to the scene so this GameObject can collider with a floor.
>
> public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     public float speed = 6.0f;
>     public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
>     public float gravity = 20.0f;
>
>     private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
>     private CharacterController controller;
>
>     void Start()
>     {
>         controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
>
>         // let the gameObject fall down
>         gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
>     }
>
>     void Update()
>     {
>         if (controller.isGrounded)
>         {
>             // We are grounded, so recalculate
>             // move direction directly from axes
>
>             moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
>             moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
>             moveDirection = moveDirection * speed;
>
>             if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
>             {
>                 moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
>             }
>         }
>
>         // Apply gravity
>         moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
>
>         // Move the controller
>         controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: i am using unity 2019.1 and when i remove this line of code it moves on global direction **which i don't want** so i still don't understand this why when i convert it from local to global it moves on local

Comment: @MohamedAfify I was wrong about 2019.1 - `CharacterController.Move` didnt change, the documentation just got worse.  I edited my answer to explain what's going on

Answer (score 1):

## Your `movement` vector is in local space

You want the player to move forward *locally* and move horizontally *locally* and so you construct a forward/rightward `movement` vector based on the player input. This vector is in *local* coordinates and you `TransformDirection` back to *world* space before applying the result to *world* position with `_charController.Move` (presumably, you didn't include that method's code).